# Meteorjs display referenced document field

Tags: mongodb, meteor, one-to-many

I have the following scenario. There is a collection Suppliers and another Invited. Now Invited.supplier = Supplier._id (syntax might be wrong) Invited collection refers to Suppliers in One to Many fashion.

In my html , I have

```
<template name="mytemplate">
{{#each invited_list}}
{{supplier}}
{{f1}}
{{f2}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

I have a helper function

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
invited_list : function(){
return Invited.find({"something"});
}
});
```

I would like to display {{Suppliers.name}} instead of _id in {{supplier}} in my invited_list . What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a resolver function such as:

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
    invited_list : function(){
        return resolveSupplierToNames(Invited.find({"something"}).fetch());
    }
});

function resolveSupplierToNames(invitedList) {
    for (var i=0; i<invitedList.length; i++) {
        invitedList[i].supplier = Suppliers.findOne({_id: invitedList[i].supplier}).name;
    }

    return invitedList;
}
```

There are generally two options with mongodb, one is the above (manual). The second is to use [DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/). However I'm not sure meteor supports DBRefs completely yet. As suggested in the mongodb docs theres nothing wrong with doing it manually.

**Update**

Meteor has since introduced a *transform* function, you can do something similar like:

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
    invited_list : function(){
        return Invited.find({"something"},{transform:function(doc) {
            doc.supplier_name = Suppliers.findOne({_id: doc.supplier_id}).name;
            return doc;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I was reading this answer trying to do the same thing, and you added the transform update while I was reading it.  Thank you so much.